# How calculate elastcisearch shard count?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, elasticsearch, sharding

I am plaining to migrate [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) old index to new one. The index is used as user storage so in future user number will increase. The common scenarion - is selecting user by fileds from index. So it is obvious that more users - slower search process because elastic need to loop over large document count.

Suppose that `currentRate` is current request rate per second to elasticsearch, `currentUserNumber` is total users in elasticsearch at now, `currentNumberOfShards` is current shards number (assume for simplicity that only 2 shards are palced into one physical node).

Also it is known expected `futureRate` and `futureUserNumber`.

So is it correct fomular to estimate new number of shards for elasticsearch:

```
futureNumberOfShards = (futureRate / currentRate) * (futureUserNumber / currentUserNumber)
```

Ot there are some other condition that I do not calculate?

**Note**

I understand that elasticsearch can perform some optimnization, but such conditions are hard to calculate outside elasticsearch so it is more correct to calculate number of shards for worst scenario.

**Note 2**

In fact user can have different number of fields. For searching only 4-5 fields are used (not all users have all of them). Does this affect search performance? And how?

Answer (score 1):

For elasticsearch best perfomance is when shards count equal data nodes count. But this makes hard to increase data nodes number in future. So you can choose - to have better perfomance now, or to make some space for future nodes. In my cluster - there was two nodes in the begining, but I've made 4 shards, and now I have 4 data nodes, and perfomance is just perfect.

Answer (score -1):

less 3M documents: 1 shard
between 3M and 5M documents with an expected growth over 5M: 2 shards.
More than 5M: int (number of expected documents / 5M +1)

You find all in this link :

https://thoughts.t37.net/designing-the-perfect-elasticsearch-cluster-the-almost-definitive-guide-e614eabc1a87#9898